# Using #-*- coding: utf-8 -*- does not remove "Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file hello.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared" error

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, py2exe

I'm trying to convert a python file into an executable. So far so good. But when I try to run the executable I get the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file hello.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details"
```

This problem is widely documented, but using the given solution of adding

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the start of the line is not solving my issue.

I'm using Notepad++ editor and have even enforced the utf-8 encoding explicitly but to no avail.

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: From PEP-0263: "a magic comment must be placed into the source files either as **first or second line** in the file".

Comment: Are you using `py2exe` to create an executable? And how do you *run the executable*? I ask this because the error message looks like you are trying something like `python hello.exe`.

Comment: Yes I'm using py2exe. My command is python hello.exe. I think thats solved the problem. If I just execute hello.exe it works.

Answer (score 9):

It seems you try to run your executable with

```
python hello.exe
```

while the point of creating an executable using `py2exe` is that you don't need to use the python interpreter anymore. So the error is actually not related to an encoding problem at all (though the error message might imply this) but just a consequence of calling python with a binary file.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else mentioned, you are running "python hello.exe" or "py hello.exe".  So you are trying to run an executable with python.. Try just running the executable without python.

You simply need to run "hello.exe".