# PyCharm issue on encoding

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I am trying pycharm and facing an encoding issue. Can you please help resolve it.
code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__author__ = 'me'
import os, sys
def main():
    print repeat('mike',False)
    print repeat('mok', True)

"""
comments here..
"""
def repeat(s,exclaim):
    result = s*3
    if exclaim:
        result = result +'!!!'
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/prakashs/PycharmProjects/GooglePython/WarmUp.py
  File "C:\Python27\python.exe", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file C:\Python27\python.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Process finished with exit code 1
I have set the default encoding in pycharm to utf-8 as well. but i need to know where in pycharm we have to edit the settings.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using #-\*- coding: utf-8 -\*- does not remove "Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file hello.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636811/using-coding-utf-8-does-not-remove-non-ascii-character-x90-in-file)

Answer (score 2):

Googling for `Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file` gives [Using #-*- coding: utf-8 -*- does not remove "Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file hello.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21636811/95735) Stackoverflow question as the first hit. There you'll find answer to your question.

You have wrong command starting with `C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\python.exe...` (`python.exe` is mentioned twice) which means you try to run executable (`python.exe`) instead of script file (`WarmUp.py`).

Comment: thank you. In pycharm I have added the path to interpreter as the exe. I removed it upon which the error went away. The program was running fine from command line but just the pycharm console was throwing issue.