# Pyinstaller throwing error No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows, executable, pyinstaller

I have written a simple python file where I am trying to read a text file and writing some log to a output file. Using pyinstaller I have created a .exe file. But when I am executing the that .exe file it is throwing the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 31, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 15, in process_data
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input1.txt'
mytest returned -1
```

Here is my code.

```
import re
import sys
import mytest2

def process_data(name, course):

    tmp = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = open("out11.txt", 'w')

    if re.search("^ank", name):
        print "Yes I am here"
    else:
        print "No no wrong door"

    fr = open("input1.txt", "r")
    lines = fr.readlines()
    fr.close()

    print "Printing from input file.."
    for line in lines:
        print line.strip()

    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stdout = tmp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg1 = sys.argv[1]
    arg2 = sys.argv[2]

    process_data(arg1, arg2)
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix this one. I am doing this in Windows.

I also want to know whether this executable will work in all windows os like win 8, 8.1, 10 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `input1.txt` is not in the folder where you have the `.exe`, or the `.exe` expects you to have `input1.txt` packaged into it - that `onefile/singlefile` option in pyinstaller.

Comment: It is in the same folder and i have used --onefile option in pyinstaller

Comment: try to package `input1.txt` into your `.exe` or pass the path of the file as an argument

Comment: Hey thanks. It is not throwing that error. But I am getting different error now.

Comment: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file test1.exe on line 1, but no enco
ding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: I have added # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- and tried still it is giving above error. Do you have any idea on that

Comment: I think this is your \x90 [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636811/using-coding-utf-8-does-not-remove-non-ascii-character-x90-in-file)

Comment: Well, run your `.exe` with double-clicking or in console type only .exe's name. Or there's a chance you copypasted something bad into your file and the character is invisible, so delete your first line and type it manually.